# Importing .txt into Excel with VBA not adding a column

Tags: excel, vba, text, import

I have this code to import a .txt file to my Excel sheet (`Sheet1`). In `Sheet1` I have the first column with a formula, so I import my text data into B1.
This code does it well the first time, however the following ones adds a column to the right, moving the selected cells in the formula of column A. The data is copied in B1 still, but somehow adding a column first. Any help?

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Select
Columns("B:F").Select
Selection.ClearContents

Dim Ret

Ret = Application.GetOpenFilename("Text Files (*.txt), *.txt", Title:="Select text file(.txt)")

If Ret <> False Then
    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
    "TEXT;" & Ret, Destination:=Range("$B$1"))
    .FieldNames = True
    .RowNumbers = False
    .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
    .PreserveFormatting = True
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
    .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
    .SavePassword = False
    .SaveData = True
    .AdjustColumnWidth = True
    .RefreshPeriod = 0
    .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
    .TextFilePlatform = 437
    .TextFileStartRow = 1
    .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
    .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
    .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
    .TextFileTabDelimiter = True
    .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
    .TextFileCommaDelimiter = True
    .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
    .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1, 1, 1, 1, 2)
    .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With

End If
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change
  `.RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells` to  `.RefreshStyle = xlOverWriteCells`, then run the macro just once. After that you can simply have Excel do the work by hitting the refresh data button on the data tab and get rid of the macro.
See: http://jkp-ads.com/articles/importtext.asp

Comment: that is perfect, many thanks! where can I read more about all these details?

Comment: In the article I already mentioned above I guess? Or are you looking for other information?

Comment: yes I read it. I mean, for instance, if I want to import an space delimited .txt file, how do I change this same code? Or any other change... mamy thanks

Comment: The crux is that you actually do not need any VBA code, just use the Excel userinterface as described in the article.